# Creating inner anonymous classes that extend other classes

Tags: java, abstract, anonymous-inner-class

I know this works:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        AbstractClass object = new AbstractClass(){ ... };
    }
}
```

It creates an object with implicitly extends the `AbstractClass` class (Which is obviously `abstract`).

But will the following work too?

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ConcreteClass object = new ConcreteClass (){ ... };
    }
}
```

ConcreteClass being a class which isn't `abstract`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most certainly, this would work: the class that you extend into an anonymous class does not need to be abstract - it could be *any* non-`final` class, or even an interface (in which case you would need to implement all its methods).

Moreover, when the class is non-abstract, you could subclass without overriding any of its methods. This feature was used in the so-called type-safe enum pattern, which has been common prior to introduction of `enum` classes into Java.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `final` classes cannot be extended in this fashion.